# Do I go with Big-Table with NULL values or non-NULL Multi-Tables Design?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

In the following Tables: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a28b23/6/0

Which is best Design should I go with?

The Big-One Design:

```
##BIG_ONE //ALL
SELECT * FROM  bigdocs ;

##BIG_ONE //18+
SELECT * FROM  bigdocs  WHERE age >= 18;

##BIG_ONE //18-
SELECT * FROM  bigdocs  WHERE age < 18;
```

Or the Multi-One Design:

```
##MULTI-ONE //ALL
SELECT * FROM  docs_18 
UNION ALL
SELECT  id ,  name ,  age , NULL, NULL FROM  docs ;

##MULTI-ONE //18+
SELECT * FROM  docs_18 ;

##MULTI-ONE //18-
SELECT * FROM  docs ;

##MULTI-ONE //18-
SELECT * FROM docs;
```

each Query presents a single usage and not all-at-once usage, Which is the better design that I should go with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place to start is whether each row represents different *entities*.  That is, if you have foreign key relationships, would you expect to have separate relationships for the under 18 crowd versus everyone else.

I would guess that you want a foreign key relationship to be to anyone regardless of age.  For instance, you might have a separate table of languages a person speaks, nicknames a person uses, pets a person owns,  emails a person users, and so on.  These would relate to people regardless of their age.

This strongly suggests one table.

What you might want to do is have a *view* on the table for each group of people.  You could even partition the table by the age groups for performance reasons.

But, there is no *a priori* reason to split a perfectly reasonable entity into two different tables.

One important consideration is if the two groups have different *security* requirements.  Security is often easier to enforce at the table level than at the row level, so this would be a consideration (not at all suggested by the question, though).

Comment: If I went with `bigdocs`, If it has a Million record, Would it still be as fast as a `docs_18` single-query If I had `Index` on `age` and used `WHERE age >= 18`? Overall, I care about performance the most.

Comment: Have you considered the performance of having to move records every time someone has a birthday?

Comment: @DanBracuk What do you mean by "**move records every time someone has a birthday**" exactly?

Comment: @Toleo . . . I think he really means "18th birthday".

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oh, Now I understand, I'm supposed in each year to run `SELECT[18-] > INSERT[18+] > DELETE[18-]`, Actually, That the exact reason I asked this question, Everytime , But I would move to `Single Table` gladly if there is no different in performance while having `INDEX` on `age`, What concerns me more is if `SELECT * FROM `bigdocs` WHERE age >= 18` is equal to `SELECT * FROM `docs_18`` In speed, More like `INDEX` = `FULLSCAN` or not..